# trying to UPDATE SQL after one SQL

Tags: php, sql

I am calculating AGE by DATE from DOB field, then I want to push it into  AGE with correct age based on DOB .   So As I debug The DOB calculating to AGE is works, but it cannot update AGE the code:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "usernameexmaple";
$password = "passworking";
$dbname = "dbnameworking";

// Create connection

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT  id as ID,  YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - YEAR(dob) - (RIGHT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 5) < RIGHT(dob, 5)) as age 
  FROM regio_users";
     $sql2 = ("UPDATE regio_users SET age = '$newage' WHERE id ='$newid' ");
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $newage = $row['age'];
        $newid  = $row['ID'];
     $sql2 = ("UPDATE regio_users SET age = '$newage' WHERE id ='$newid' ");
     $result2 = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result2){
    echo "done"."<br>";
}
     }

    }
 else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

It echos  DONE for every ID but not  updating anything at all.

Comment: `$result2 = $conn->query($sql2);` use `$sql2` to run update query

Comment: Thanks a lot, gotta read my sscript again before I post here. Sorry for wasting time and thanks a lot for catching it for me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used `$result2 = $conn->query($sql);` which is incorrect. You have to use `$result2 = $conn->query($sql2);` as `$sql2` is the new query you formed.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a single line SQL, rather than using PHP to loop through all the rows to only update the age:

```
UPDATE `regio_users` SET `age` = YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - YEAR(`dob`) - (RIGHT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 5) < RIGHT(`dob`, 5));
```

Answer (score 0):

1. As saty pointed, use correct variable name.
2. Check if autocommit is on. If not, make sure you commit the data. Check for its syntax in PHP.